# How to get selected values from drop-down list in filterToolbar using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, struts2-jquery

I want to filter the grid based on the selected value in **filterToolbar**.

**This is my grid**

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="assigned_to"   index="assigned_user" key="assigned_user" title="Assigned To"   
            sortable="false"
            searchtype="select"
            searchoptions="{defaultSearch:'cn', dataUrl : '%{fillUser}', 
                           dataEvents: [{ type: 'change' fn: function(elem) { myfunction(elem)}}]}"/>
```

So problem is

1: how to get the selected values from drop-down list  in function **myfunction(elem)** which is fired using **dataEvents**.

2:  what is **elem** in this **dataEvents** options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One use typically the name `event` or `e` as the name of the parameter of `fn` function because the parameter is [jQuery Event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). The most important its property if `target` which will be DOM element of select (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp)). So you can use [selectedIndex](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp) and [options](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp) properties to get information about selected option:

```js
fn: function (e) {
    var selectDOM = e.target,
        selectedOptionDOM = selectDOM.options[selectDOM.selectedIndex];

    alert("selected option has\n" +
        "text=" + selectedOptionDOM.text +
        "\nvalue=" + selectedOptionDOM.value);
}
```

Alternatively you can use jQuery to get selected option. `$(e.target).val()` provide the value of selected option and `$(e.target).find(":selected").text()` gives you its text:

```js
fn: function (e) {
    var $select = $(e.target);

    alert("selected option has\n" +
        "text=" + $select.find(":selected").text() +
        "\nvalue=" + $select.val());
}
```

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.

Comment: please check this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068668/how-to-load-json-in-jqgrid , I am stuck here

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk: I can repeat only that you should better use `reloadGrid` instead of manual call of `$.ajax`. You can change `url` or `postData` using `setGridParam` before trigger `reloadGrid`.