# jqGrid not displaying data... JSON string is true JSON... Do I need a jsonReader

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

This is just a section of my JSON Data string as it is quite extensive...

```
{
    "total": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 15,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 2148,
            "cell": {
                "MRN": "840134833",
                "Hospital_Fin": "987141516",
                "First_Name": "YELLOW",
                "Last_Name": "CRAYON",
                "Date_of_birth": "/Date(1253160000000)/"}
         }
      ]}
```

And this would be how I set up my jqGrid...

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#frTable").jqGrid ({
            cmTemplate: { sortable: false },
            caption: '@TempData["POPNAME"]' + ' Population',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetAjaxPagedGridData", "Encounters", new { popId = TempData["POPULATIONID"] })',//'/Encounters/GetAjaxPagedGridData/'+ '',                
            pager: '#pager',
            loadonce: true,
            height: 450,
            gridview: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            rowNum: 15,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            autowidth: true,
            colNames: [
                   'MRN',
                   'Hospital Fin',
                   'First Name',
                   'Last Name',
                   'Date of birth'
            colModel: [
                   { name: 'MRN', width: 125, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Hospital_Fin', width: 145, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'First_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Last_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                   { name: 'Date_of_birth', width: 145, align: 'left', formatter:'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'm/d/Y'}}]
```

Now...
I look through JSfiddle and I do get the Json string back in the right format.  In fact, That is how I was able to copy and paste to this fine website.  So what am I missing?  It looks like everything should be about right?

**UPDATE**
Do my col models and the names of my columns in my cell have to match up 100 percent?  Maybe that would be someplace to take a look?

Comment: could you help pleade 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417220/load-data-for-jqgrid-using-json-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use wrong format of JSON data. Compare your data with the data expected by jqGrid described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data). To fix JSON data you can change it to for example the following

```
{
    "total": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "records": 15,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 2148,
            "MRN": "840134833",
            "Hospital_Fin": "987141516",
            "First_Name": "YELLOW",
            "Last_Name": "CRAYON",
            "Date_of_birth": "/Date(1253160000000)/"
        }
    ]
}
```

You need include additionally `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}` in the list of jqGrid options.

Comment: does jsonReader is also needed  when we create jqgrid with struts2-jqgrid-plugin

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk: All depends on the format of data which returned from the server. If The data are like in my answer above one have to use `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}` additionally.

Comment: i did this, but nothing really changed, please have a look a this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068668/how-to-load-json-in-jqgrid

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk: I don't use struts2 myself and I I don't understand what you do in the question. Moreover I find wrong the usage of `addJSONData` in most cases (see one from my first [posts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2660226/315935) on the stackoverflow). One should add some parameters in `postData` and use reloadGrid instead of `addJSONData`. Probably you will be able to fix your problem by replacing `complete` callback to `success` inside of `filterFunction`, but it's just guessing.

Comment: okay skip struts2, guess if there is an already constructed grid and I want to load that grid with some json-data based on an event then how to achieve this, Note :  that grid is previously loaded with some data, I want to reload this grid with some new json-data, then what will be your strategies using jqgrid?

Comment: @arvin_codeHunk: You write comments to the answer which has no relation with your comments. To reload the data in the grid you need just call `trigger("reloadGrid")`. Before it you can set `postData` to send additional parameters to the `url` of just change `url`. So I recommend you to fill the grid always by requests to `url` of the grid.

Comment: sorry hijacking for this post,But I indeed in trouble thats why I found you here,  will you please check updated section in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068668/how-to-load-json-in-jqgrid

Comment: Well, I'll be damned.  It worked!  I thought that a cell type was needed.

Comment: @DmainEvent: You are not the first person who makes the same error. You are welcome!