# Load data for jqgrid using json doesn't work

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting crazy, could you help me please,
the grid rows doesn't appear and i don't know why it is really disturbing i spent more than 3 days trying, i realllly need help here!!!!

My Action Method:

```
  [HttpGet]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        public JsonResult GetSearches(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows,string name)
        {
            var ls = db.Candidates.Select(

                z => new
                {
                    z.ID,
                    z.Name,
                    z.Email
                }
                );             
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;

            int totalRecords = ls.Count();
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            {
                ls = ls.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(name));

            }
            if(sord.ToUpper()=="DESC")
            {

                ls = ls.OrderByDescending(x => x.Name);
                ls = ls.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            }
            else
            {
                ls = ls.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                ls = ls.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

            }
            var jsonData = new
            {

                total = totalPages,
                page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = ls

            };
            return Json(jsonData);
        }
```

My View :

```
@using MGroup.Data.Models
@model Candidate

@{
    Layout = "~/views/shared/_layouttestgrid.cshtml";

}
<fieldset>
    <div id="parent">

        <div style="float:left;width:35%;">
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "filterItem" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="button" id="filterButton" name="search" value="filter" />
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<br />
<div>
    <table id="grid"></table>
    <div id="pager">

    </div>
</div>

<link href="~/JqGrid/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/JqGrid/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/JqGrid/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/JqGrid/scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/JqGrid/scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/JqGrid/scripts/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/JqGrid/Scripts/MyList.js"></script>
```

My JavaScript File:

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: '/Candidate/GetSearches',
        dataType: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',

        colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Email'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'ID', index: 'ID' },
            { key: false, name: 'Name', index: 'Name' },
            { key: false, name: 'Email', index: 'Email' }
        ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        loadone: false,
        caption: 'Searches',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',

        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records:"records",
            repeatitems: false,
            Id: "0"
        },
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false
    })
     .navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true });

    $('#filterButton').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        filterGrid();
    });
});

function filterGrid() {

    var postDataValues = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');

    $('.filterItem').each(function (index, item) {

        postDataValues[$(item).attr('id')] = $(item).val();
    });
    $('#grid').jqGrid().setGridParam({ postData: postDataValues, page: 1 }).trigger('reloadGrid');

}
```

Comment: Are you able to hit the GetSearches method? where are you passing the parameters for GetSearches method?

Comment: You should post more details. What error you have? Do you see empty grid or nothing? Is `GetSearches` ever called? Do you tried to use Developer Tools (press F12 to start) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to make HTTP trace of the traffic between jqGrid and the server? If you can see response from `GetSearches` then you should append your question with the JSON response. **Which version of jqGrid you use?**

Comment: Thank you guys specially @Oleg i corrected by using some informations from you old posts ;)

Comment: @Oleg how can we add custom filter to subgrid not to the main grid? thnx.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. It's better if you post new question where you explain what you do currently, how you use jqGrid and what is your problem. It's important to know which version of jqGrid (and which fork of jqGrid) you use. Which `datatype` have the grid? Do you use `loadonce: true` (and so the filtering will be on the client side) or now? How you implemented subgrid? Do you use grid as subgrid? Do you load subgrid data togother with the data of main grid or fill subgrid separately. What you mean under "custom filter"? A good example would clear many things.

Comment: hi Oleg,in fact i'm doing the filtering on server side, can you take a look please [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569316/how-can-we-joined-custom-filter-to-the-subgrid-not-the-main-grid)